# Python syntax for an unless statement

Tags: python

My request is simple but I do not know how to proceed:

I would like to translate an unless statement in python as followed:

```
taken_asks -= 1 unless taken_asks == 0
```

This is just one line of code which is part of a very big function. 
Any idea?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: `if taken_asks != 0: taken_asks -= 1`?

Comment: @Nenri That doesn't really make sense unless something should be done multiple times.

Comment: @Nenri, nope because I want to modify `taken_asks` only one time, a while loop will do it many time

Comment: This should work: ```taken_asks -= 1 if taken_asks else 0```

Comment: `taken_asks -= bool(taken_asks)`

Comment: Do you want to prevent it from being negative also?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`taken_asks -= (1 if taken_asks != 0 else 0)`

Answer (score 4):

For me most obvious solution is turning `unless` into `if not`, in this case:

```
if not taken_asks == 0:
    taken_asks -= 1
```

which can be written in one-line form

```
if not taken_asks == 0: taken_asks -= 1
```

Other ways exist, but I think this is handful if you need readibility.

Comment: I'd find this more readable as `if taken_tasks != 0:`, but this is still the most sane solution *by a long shot*.

Answer (score 3):

A bit shorter.

```py
taken_asks -= (taken_asks != 0)
# (taken_asks != 0) is a boolean value, boolean value in Python is int.
# True is 1, False is 0
```

or

```py
taken_asks = max(taken_asks-1, 0)
```

Comment: this works : `taken_asks -= taken_asks != 0` (no need for parenthesis there)

Comment: Heads up: If you use this in your code, you're putting yourself in danger of being killed during your next code review.

Comment: why ? it just depends of what is readable for you or not. I've absolutely no problem with this for example. But that's maybe because I often play with ternaries and one liners

Answer (score 1):

Using ternary condition:

```
taken_asks = 0    
taken_asks -= 1 if taken_asks else 0    
print(taken_asks)   # 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but the simplest version may be:

```
taken_asks -= bool(taken_asks)
```

---

[Demo](https://ideone.com/GUx8FJ)

---

**Explanation**:

`Boolean` type variable inherit from `int` and can be used in arithmetic operations, i.e.:

1. `bool(< 1)` returns `None/False` (`int(0)`)
2. `bool(> 0)` returns  `True` (`int(1)`)

Comment: Didn't notice, deleted, posted  a new version.